# Trouble importing gradle project (LibGdx) in eclipse from git repo

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github, libgdx

I am trying to set up a git repo to use for a project I would like to start working on. I have created an online repo on GitHub for the project. The project is a LibGdx project using a gradle configuration.

https://github.com/RiverFloater/MathTutorApplication

I can clone the repo to the computer with out any issues. When I go to import it to eclipse I can not get the project to run. I have tried importing different ways with no success. I have imported as a gradle project from the local repo created after cloning. I have also tried as a general project but that fails as well. The import will complete and the files will be displayed but I can not run the project.

The project runs fine on the computer I created it on and can commit with out any issues. Unfortunately, I am new to git and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any assistance would be appreciated. If it is a problem with the gradle configuration then I will have to do more research as the gradle wrapper was done using the LibGdx project creator and will have to familiarize my self with that as that is new to me as well.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well I finally resolved the issue. I didn't commit and push the rest of the gradle configurations and dependencies to the repo. Therefor, when I would pull it was missing the proper configurations to build out the gradle